# How to convert existing html file to pdfs in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I have an html file generate_invoice.html.erb. I have to provide a button on the same file to convert generate_invoice.html.erb into a downloadable pdf.I have tried using wicked pdf gem and gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

then I also created the config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb and set the mime types to pdf

my routes is as follows:

```
match 'orders/:id/invoice'      => 'orders#order_invoice', as:   
'order_invoice', via: [:put,:post,:get]
```

My order_controller is as follows

```
 def order_invoice
  @base_url = ENV['base_url']
  @order = Order.includes(:status, :user, payment: 
  [:status]).where(id: params[:id]).first
  if (['Notary', 'Attestation','Franking'].include? 
  @order.service.name)
    @no_of_copies = ((@order.answers.where(question_id: 
    [37,15]).length
    > 0) ? @order.answers.where(question_id: [37,15]).first.body : 
    0).to_i 
  else
    @no_of_copies = ((@order.answers.where(question_id: 
    [37,15]).length 
    > 0) ? @order.answers.where(question_id: [37,15]).first.body : 
    0).to_i + 1
  end

  render 'order_mailer/generate_invoice',layout: false
  respond_to do |format|
   format.pdf do
     render pdf: "order_invoice"
  end 
end
```

end

it however throws this error

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat at /admin/orders/131/invoice
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

basically it is pointing at **respond_to do |format|** line

What am I doing wrong.Please help me rectify this.Also please let me know the next course of action to achieve the pdf format

Comment: try to add format.html as well after ... |format|

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `order_invoice` file has a format of `order_invoice.html.erb` instead of `order_invoice.pdf.erb` which should be the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "order_invoice"   
  end
end
```

and I hope you already have the view file "order_invoice.html.erb"

Comment: Actually I have to use the file generate_invoice.html.erb here. Also now that I tried the code, it throws this error for the controller  :                 Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".